# problem related to denseness

Tags: general-topology

let $S$ be the collection of all the seq. $(x_n)$ where $x_n$’s belong to rationals and are non zero for finitely many $n$. Then $S$ is dense in

A) $\ell_1(\Bbb R)$ set of all absolute summable seq.
B) $\ell_2(\Bbb R)$ set of all square summable seq.
C) $\ell_\infty$ set of all bounded seq.

and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given sequence $x_n$ (either of type A, B or C) with possibly infinitely many zeroes, you can get a sequence of sequences $(y_{k,n})_n\ \in S$ for $k=1,2,3,\dots$, such that you simply cut $x_n$ above $k$, i.e.:
$$y_{k,n}:= \left\{ \begin{matrix} x_n & \text{if }\ n\le k \\
0 &\text{if }\ n>k \end{matrix} \right. \ .$$
Then the limit of sequences $\ {\bf y}_k:=(y_{k,n})_n\ $ will be the sequence ${\bf x} = (x_n)_n\ $ according to the convergence defined in the given spaces.

**Update:**
In case of A) and B), any such sequence $x_n$ must tend to $0$ (because $\sum x_n$ or $\sum x_n^2$ converges), but for the *bounded* sequences (case C) this is not the case.

A sequence of sequences ${\bf y}_k$ converges to the sequence $\bf x$ in $\ell_\infty$ iff $||{\bf y}_k-{\bf x}||_\infty= \max_n\, |y_{k,n}-x_n| \ \to 0 $ as $k\to\infty$.

Now, for example the constant sequence ${\bf x}:=(1,1,1,1,\dots)\in \ell_\infty$, but if ${\bf y}\in S$, then $||{\bf x}-{\bf y}||_\infty \ge 1 $ because $y_n=0$ for a lot $n$'s.

Comment: answer to this ques are A) and B) only, but i dont know how

Comment: Ah, ok, extended my answer.